# How to hook every creation of a new String instance?

Tags: javascript, string, debugging, hook

Is it possible to hook the creation of every new `String`?  Everytime code like this is run:

```js
const new_string = 'Hello World!';
```

I want to be notified; for instance;

```js
console.log('A new String was created:', whatever_new_string_was_created);
```

Comment: This is pretty core to JavaScript, so I'm going to guess no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are primitives with no events associated, and the constructor has no way to change it's methods: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string-objects